# fopen() hanging in php: profiler says it's called from script host. What does this mean?

Tags: php, xdebug, sugarcrm

My Sugar CRM PHP application is hanging on my server. I installed Xdebug and it tells me that the `fopen()` function is hanging (see image), and that it's "called from script host". It's not clear to me what a "script host" is and how I can debug this...[image]

Comment: The script host is the host where the script is running. Being PHP, it's the server.

Comment: what "show call graph" did ? can you not step in to the call??